# Compare custom taxonomies of updated post (or new post) [Updated with progress]

Tags: save-post, transient

I am using the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to cache category loops for a custom taxonomy. All works fine, but if I add a new post or update an existing one, I woud like to compare the taxonomy values and then clear the transients based on the difference in IDs and then clear the others. Transients have the following format, `_transient_mouldings_cat_loop_141` where `141` is the ID.

Does anyone have any suggestions on grabbing the tax values before the post is saved (existing terms) (which I thought would be [`category_save_pre()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference), but that only references post categories, and then on-save, use [`save_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) to grab the new values, find the difference and then delete the needed transients?

Thanks!

## Update

I was able to delete category transients with `save_post()`:

```
function mouldings_delete_transient_teaser($post_id) {
    switch (get_post_type()) {
        case 'moulding_profiles':
            // delete teaser transient
            delete_transient('mouldings_moulding_profiles_teaser_'.$post_id);

            // delete profile category transient
            $post_terms = get_the_terms($post_id, 'profile_categories');
            foreach ($post_terms as $post_term) {
                delete_transient('mouldings_cat_loop_'.$post_term->term_id);
            }
            break;
    }

}
add_action('save_post','mouldings_delete_transient_teaser');
```

but I still need to be able to plug into the initial load. I was thinking [`load_(page)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-%28page%29) might do the trick, an I could possibly create a function in there that grabs the posts before an item is saved, but then calling that function in `save_post()` would probably just give me the new categories (which I already have). Any suggestions are welcome

## Thoughts

I'm wondering if this is more along the lines of storing the category IDs in a session variable - then on `save_post()` compare those with `get_terms()` (which will have the new ones) and then the unique IDs would be run through the `delete_transient()` function --- as I have still yet to come across anything...

*Thoughts continued*:

It sounds like sessions are not used in WordPress and while you can enable them via `wp-config.php`, I'm wondering if there is a simpler way that I'm missing.

## Update #2

After more than a few back 'n forths with Tom, I believe this is the correct way to go:

```
function mouldings_delete_transients ($object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy, $append, $old_tt_ids) {

    if (get_post_type() == 'moulding_profiles' || get_post_type() == 'moulding_combination') {
        $changed_cats = array_diff($tt_ids, $old_tt_ids);
        foreach ($changed_cats as $changed_cat) {
            delete_transient('mouldings_cat_loop_'.$changed_cat);
        }
    }
}
add_action('set_object_terms', 'mouldings_delete_transients', 10, 6);
```

The only problem I'm having with this is `$old_tt_ids` are not being called when a post is saved. So, what I'm trying to do is compare the current categories, `$tt_ids` with the old categories, `$old_tt_ids` and detect the changes between the two. So, if a new category has been chosen, that would be part of the diff. And, if a category was removed (unchecked), that would also be chosen. It seems to grab the new ones, but not the old ones. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I am not following what exactly are you cashing and what data is involved. Please try to make more clear what are you storing and what your cache invalidation conditions precisely are.

Comment: Hi @Rarst thanks for the reply. I am caching the `WP_Query` that generates each taxonomy ([example](http://i48.tinypic.com/34oonl2.jpg)). The problem isn't the caching itself, it's more clearing those transients that are attached to each category loop. Each category transient is appended with the cat id, so what I'm trying to do on post-save, is compare the categories it now has to the ones it did have and if there are any differences, delete those transients (whether categories were removed or added). I have 'em set to expire after an hour, but I'd like it to be more seamless. Thanks!

Comment: It should be enough to delete the transient, any future attempt to grab it should force a recreation. You should post your transient deletion on save code as an answer and mark it as correct

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell to clarify, the transient appends on the category ID to the end of the transient name (as mentioned in the OQ), so even if there were a way to "wildcard" all int values at the end of the transient name, it defeats the purpose of using a "russian doll" effect of caching very specific parts of the site (so that when a transient is cleared, there's less for it to do to regenerate). I'm trying to get a list of the categories attached to a post "before" save, but "on-save", compare them and if there are differences, use those cat ids to delete the needed transients.

Comment: then hook into the term setting..

Comment: Also keep in mind that caching is not a silver bullet. It may even be possible that the overhead of your caching and checks is greater than the savings you're making, and your site gets slower not faster

Comment: @TomJNowell I'd appreciate a link or example to get me started with the term setting - that's kinda what I'm asking for here. The part that's been confusing is how I could call this during `save_post` without getting the active (or new) terms and not the original ones from the initial post-load.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `set_object_terms` hook,

http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/set_object_terms?version=3.4&file=wp-includes/taxonomy.php

It should be fired when a post or page is modified.

Here is the code that fires it:

```
do_action('set_object_terms', $object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy, $append, $old_tt_ids);
```

You can thus check against the $object_id and taxonomy, and flush your transient cache and regenerate as needed.

Specifically, clear the term caches of the term IDs in `$tt_ids` and `$old_tt_ids`

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell thanks for that. I took a look and saw that the `$old_tt_ids` was added a [few years ago](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10962). The `wp_set_object_terms` has a `$delete_terms` variable that looks to have exactly what I need (as it compares the old and new), but I'm a little unclear on how I can access that from within `save_post`. Would you be able to show me an example of that? It doesn't look like `$delete_terms` would have the new ones (hence the var name), so I'm assuming I would also keep my original `delete_transient()` func on the new ones. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't access it from `save_post`, that's a different, separate, unrelated hook. It's also negligent of the fact that one may modify the terms fo a post without saving/editing/publishign said post.

Comment: Instead, assume that when the terms of an object are set in the taxonomy you are watching, that the terms will have changed, else that hook would never have been called. You already have everything required passed via the filter, stop overcomplicating things by requesting variables that contain data you already have ( old_tt_ids? not that you even need to check those!! If it's the taxonomy you're watching, and the object type you want, clear the transient, it's as simple as that, stop confusing things )

Comment: Also what would you do if you had access to the `delete_terms` variable? Do a `get_Term` call? But wait those terms have been deleted and are no longer in the DB! I can see you'll want to find an earlier hook then, but wait, if the terms never changed, the hook would never have been called...

Comment: I think we might be off track (don't think `delete_terms` is what I need). The reason I hooked into `save_post` was that when a post is saved, I could get the current categories it has been placed in and clear the transients wrapped around each frontend WP_Query ([example](http://i48.tinypic.com/34oonl2.jpg)). I'm trying to find the difference (if any) between what a post "used" to be tagged-in (before-save) and what it is "after-save" to clear the transients on the frontend so the post doesn't show up in an out-of-date category query. So, the terms are not deleted, just removed from the post.

Comment: Your last comment may be right (if I need an earlier hook) but thought I'd explain again for clarity.

Comment: set object terms sets the object terms, it doesn't add/append/modify/remove, it sets them, here are the terms A B and C, the terms are now A B and C, all previous term relationships are irrelevant. use that hook, if there has been no change then the hook will never have been called.

Comment: I'm also of the opinion that even without this you've strayed down the road of micro-optimising anyway

Comment: aka old_tt_id and tt_ids should all be cleared

Comment: When the initial query count is over 700, you tend to think a little like this :) I'll look into this a bit more and see what I can find. I really appreciate all the help

Comment: That's a lot of posts to grab and display, just be careful your Russian dolls caching doesn't get too deep, I'd say using taxonomies as caches to speed things up would be a good idea, but I suspect you're already doing that

Comment: Yup - I'm using a custom WP_Query on those tax pages which grabs all the top level cats and then four posts for each. So based on your other comment, it may not actually store what I need? I'm almost thinking about creating a transient on each page load with the old taxonomies (before update) and then on save post compare that to what's currently there - but I think idea stems from my lack of knowledge how to actually use old_tt_ids in this case

Comment: old_tt_ids are old term IDs, tt_ids are the new term IDs. Just clear the associated caches for said term IDs

Comment: That and generating a transient on each page load to compare kind of defeats the point of caching in transients in the first place, as you're doing the work anyway.

Comment: Well, I'd be comparing just on page load in the admin to see if I need to clear transients on the front-end (based on taxonomy assignment changes in the post itself). So, if a post is saved and there are no changes between the old taxonomies and the new ones, then it doesn't clear anything - otherwise, it deltes the transient for each category loop in cache so it can display the proper posts on the front-end. At the end of the day, this sounds like `save_post()` happens too late for me to delete the transient there (and that I should be using `set_object_terms`) which I'm still muddy on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6090/discussion-between-zach-and-tom-j-nowell)

Comment: Everything you need is already here, $old_tt_ids and $tt_ids are arrays contianing integers, aka the term IDs of the terms that are and were set. Clear/remove/burn/pillage/delete/destroy/annihilate the associated transients. It really is that simple

Comment: foreach ID in old_tt_ids { delete the transient for that ID } repeat again for the other array

Comment: I know we're almost there, http://pastebin.com/bHUWyhg6 that gets rid of new terms, but not the old ones (when a previously selected term id is unchecked and then the post is updated).

Comment: I updated my answer with my progress - any idea why `$old_tt_ids` does not have those "old term ids"?